# cAPGi-5HaxD2HaxD Wifi AP drops all connection every few days

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

I have recently bought an cAPGi-5HaxD2HaxD Mikrotik ap, but unfortunately I have a very annoying issue with it. The router drops all WIFI clients every 2-3 days, and it doesn't let them to reconnect, unless I make a power off. In windows when I trying to reconnect it says: "Some information changed since the last time you connected. We need additional information to complete the connection."

I will add the screenshot of the logs as an attachment. If you have any idea please, let me know.[image]